# Yocto iotivity query

Tags: embedded-linux, iot, yocto, bitbake, iotivity

I have followed below steps provide to Build yocto image boot from SD card and able to successfully run sample iotivity from artik board.

https://blogs.s-osg.org/run-iotivity-artik-yocto/

http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-oic/about/

I have few query here, check if you can help on this.

1. The yocto –project mention to include Iotivity packages in `meta-oic` layer . All the packages are include from github path. I included all packages and verify as they had mentioned to check at specific path.  After booting image  I tried to compile my wrapper cpp file from artik-board with yocto-image hopping it will compile since i have header and lib present in my yocto-image.  But they failed.   I didn’t understand the usage of iotivity packages included in yocto-image. How can a developer use them directly on atrik board ?
2. I have iotivity code in my ubuntu machine and I can compile a my .cpp wrapper  file with the Scons.   How can i add my only cpp file with this yocto image?
3. Below is a description provide in yocto-project to follow.

## Building IoTivity applications for a Yocto target

1. Develop and test your application on a Linux development machine.
2. You can now use the Yocto toolchain for your target to cross-compile the
   application. As such, there is no standard procedure for this.
   You may examine your toolchain’s environment setup script and accordingly
   modify your application’s build script to point to said tools.
3. If you further want to package up your application in a Yocto software layer,
   you will have to write a BitBake recipe for it. Look inside
   `meta-oic/recipes-apps/iotivity-simple-client` for a precise example of doing
   this.

`meta-oic/recipes-apps/iotivity-simple-client` when I check is also actually using source code/libs path  from github directly .  This example have contain .dat file, makefile, .tar, .bb file and .jason file . I checked on internet everyone explained  how to create new meat-layer and add new bitkake recipe but all use build source code from github. 
However my code is on local host and is totally linked with my iotivity source code folder.

Can any one suggest clear steps on this.

Answer (score 1):

I can help if you can post the error messages. I would request you to read the following blogs as well. If you follow the information in these links.
[IoTivity on Yocto](https://wiki.iotivity.org/yocto)

You should be able to find the iotivity client and server binaries in

```
/opt/iotivity/examples/resource/cpp/simpleserver
/opt/iotivity/examples/resource/cpp/simpleclient
```

Much of the build process is self explanatory. If you still face issues please get back with the error logs.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)